# how to get last entry in given date range from pivot table

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Ok, i'm stuck and really need help pls.

this is setup:

1) table items: id, name

2) table statuses: id, title

3) table item_status: id, item_id, status_id, created_at

item model has relation:

```
public function statuses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

now, i want items with LATEST statuses '7' or '9', created between 2015-10-19 and 2015-10-20
closest i got is:

```
$items = Item::with('statuses')->whereHas('statuses', function ($q) {
                                        $q->where('created_at','>=','2015-10-19');
                                        $q->where('created_at','<','2015-10-20');
                                        $q->whereIn('status_id',array('7','9'));
                                    }
                    );
```

Problem is that this is not working right. **It gives all items that got one of these status_id's in that date range**. 
So if item got status '7' on 2015-10-19, and for example status '11' on 2015-10-22, it will be in result. I would like to have **only items with latest (newest) status '7' or '9' in that date range**.

**Update:**
for example: table item_status

```
item_id status_id   created_at
1          1       2015-10-06
1          3       2015-10-07
2          6       2015-10-07
2          3       2015-10-08
2          5       2015-10-09
```

if i set filter as: status_id = 3 and date range 2015-10-06 to 2015-10-09: i want only ITEM 1, because ITEM 2 in given period has another, newer status (5)

please help!
tnx
Y

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `->withTimestamps()` function for relationship when your are using timestamp columns

Ex:

```
public function statuses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's true. I edited question, but that's not enough. I still get all items that had given statuses in given period, and not only items which have given statuses AS LAST ONE in that period.